# Can you kill the desert birds?

Tags: candy-box-2

When going through the desert, there are birds flying over head.  Can you kill these?  Do you get anything for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can kill these birds.  The earliest method possible is using Red Enchanted Gloves (Throw a chocolate bar in the wishing well).

[image: Bird Kill]

Upon killing the bird, you will receive a "desert bird feather" in your inventory.  When hovering the mouse over the item, the text reads:

> A desert bird feather
>   For an unknown reason,
>   you feel that this
>   feather could be useful
>   if you have a pogo
>   stick...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the 'acid rain' spell which you can get from the sorceress across the bridge at the bottom of the map.